# Adding an Approved header with a mail client

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird

With older versions of **Thunderbird** I used to be able to add an `Approved` header to a message, but with later versions, even though I can get `Approved` to show up on the list of headers, when the message is sent the header is missing.  I've tried rolling back to an old version, but **Thunderbird** keeps updating itself and I can't seem to stop it.

Is there some other (Windows or Web) mail client that has this ability, or a plugin to **Outlook** or one of the others?

Alternatively, can you tell me how to stop **Thunderbird** from auto-upgrading?

Thanks.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a free [Set Field Value](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookHeadersSet/) Outlook add-in than can set any header, including "Approved". I'm one of the developers of this add-in.
2. In Thunderbird, open Tools->Options->Advanced->Update and set the "Never check for updates" option.